# How to programmatically get launch time of other apps in android?

Tags: android, time, launch

I want to get launch time of all apps in android. Please suggest me any solution to achieve this. I am using this code. It is to kill non system apps. But it is also not working. Can anybody suggest any solution for it. Thanks

```
timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {   
           List<RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses= activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        for (RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses) {
            try {
            if (appProcess.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
            if (!lastFrontAppPkg.equals((String) appProcess.pkgList[0])) {
            apkInfo = ApkInfo.getInfoFromPackageName(appProcess.pkgList[0], mContext);
                if (apkInfo == null || (apkInfo.getP().applicationInfo.flags && ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 1) {
                  // System app                                             continue;
                        } else if (((apkInfo.getP().versionName == null)) || (apkInfo.getP().requestedPermissions == null)) {
                    //Application that comes preloaded with the device
                        continue;
                     } else {
                     lastFrontAppPkg = (String) appProcess.pkgList[0];
                     }
    //kill the app
    //Here do the pupop with password to launch the lastFrontAppPkg if the pass is correct
                         }
                      }
                   }
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                  //e.printStackTrace();
                }
               }                        
             }
           }, 0, 1000);
```

Comment: build your own ROM ... `scheduleAtFixedRate` every 1s will drain battery in no time :)